# How to create PEM formatted key from email and password?

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, pgp, openpgp.js

I am using [Hybrid-Crypto.js](https://juhoen.github.io/hybrid-crypto-js/#documentation) for playing around with public/private key encryption. 
This function creates a random PEM-formatted RSA keypair

```
// Generate 2048 bit RSA key pair
rsa.generateKeypair(function(keypair) {
 // Callback function receives new 2048 bit keypair as an argument
 var publicKey = keypair.publicKey;
 var privateKey = keypair.privateKey;
 }, 2048);  // Key size
```

However, I would like to create a keypair derived from email and password like being known from [openpgp.js](https://openpgpjs.org/)

```
var options = {
  userIds: [{ name: 'Alicee', email:     'alice@example.com' }],
  numBits: 2048,
  passphrase: 'secretttoo'
};

var publicKeyAlice;
var privateKeyAlice;

openpgp.generateKey(options).then(key => {
  privateKeyAlice = key.privateKeyArmored;
  publicKeyAlice = key.publicKeyArmored;
  console.log('Key generated');
});
```

Is there a way to create PEM/RSA keypairs like PGP-keys from fixed sources such that every time the same keypair gets created when the same inputs (email/password) is entered?